# azure cli login with service principal not working with Azure Release Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-cli

I am trying to run a script to create resources at the beginning of my azure release pipeline in I am trying to login with the cli using a service principal: here is my script below

```
#!/bin/bash
az login --service-principal -u $4 -p $5 -t $6
FirstResourceGroup=$1
SecondResourceGroup=$2
Location=$3
az group create -n $FirstResourceGroup -l $Location
az group create -n $SecondResourceGroup -l $Location
```

When I run this script locally on my Mac it works perfectly, however when I run this in my Azure Release Pipeline (using a Bash script task on an Ubuntu build agent) I get the following error when the **az login --service-principal** command runs:

```
ERROR: Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I am not sure what the issue is, has anyone else encountered a similar problem?

NOTE: I am using Azure Cli 2.0.55 locally and in the hosted Ubuntu build agent

Comment: why dont you use the built-in tasks for az cli which handle the auth for you?

Comment: because I was having trouble getting a bash file to run in a az cli task with the correct parameters and I don't want to use an inline script because I want to manage it with source control. But regardless it doesn't explain why this doesn't work from the Bash script, in theory it should run the same as it does locally

Comment: one potential reason could be that you are not providing `htttp://` for the username